tiptap web-socket error in editing Unexpected end of array
I tried to generate live collaboration with Tiptap and HocuspocusProvider in Reactjs
the web socket is working well but when I want to start editing I see a weird error that is stopping me from editing the document
the code is like this
const provider = new HocuspocusProvider({
    url: "ws://localhost:8000/ws/document/edit/3f798b14-4635-4450-bc66-b05b04fbfb8f?token=" + TEST_TOKEN,
    name: "3f798b14-4635-4450-bc66-b05b04fbfb8f",
    document: ydoc,
});
    function Tiptap({
    content = '',
    editable = true,
    placeholder = "Type '/' for actions…",
}: TiptapProps) {
    const extensions: Extensions = [
        Collaboration.configure({
            document: provider.document,
        }),
        CollaborationCursor.configure({
            provider: provider,
            user: {
              name: 'Cyndi Lauper',
              color: '#f783ac',
            },
          }),
    ]
    const editor = useEditor({
        content,
        extensions,
        editable,
        onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
            console.log(editor.getJSON())
        },
    })

    if (!editor) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="WhiteCard">
                 <Toolbar editor={editor} />
                <EditorContent editor={editor} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Tiptap

and the error is

